# "Bind" linux kernel to a specific cpu?

Tags: kernel, security

I'd like to build a linux kernel that's specific to a given Raspberry, ie. one that won't boot on any other Raspberries. My idea is to bind the kernel to the cpu's serial number bit I haven't found any infos on this topic.

Yes, I know
a) I'd have to build/compile a custom kernel for every device;
b) that exchanging the kernel for a clean one would forgo this piece of "security", but there are keys stored in the kernel which are needed for userland later on which would be unavailable then.

Any "later" stages (ie. checks for a specific serial number once the kernel is booted by some userland tool) do work theoretically but are out of the question here as they could very easily (as in: easier then reverse engineering the complex kernel) be reverse engineered.

Any ideas and pointers are, as always, highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will get more ideas on Ubunut Stack. I know there are ways yo automount encrypted volumes during boot. But the key is is readable. I suspect even if you embed your keys into the kerner somebody can easily extract them too and use them on a clean kernel. This is why DRM is so successful as a web service authenticates the software/device and it lets the the software know if it has access or not, or uses a token or one time access key. So really trying to build a kernel for each Pi will be pointless as somebody will figure out how to get the keys one way or another :(

Comment: Thanks for the input (+1 ;), but I'm really not looking into DRM here but rather intellectual property safety. There's code executed later on that's to be protected from being run on *some* machine but which has to stay on this *one* machine. I am well aware that it's technically impossible to decrypt something automatically without storing the key *somewhere*, but I found the kernel to be a rather good storage for keys that are to be available at it#s own runtime *only*. This might be more of a thought experiment I guess.

Comment: You might have better luck by installing a root certificate authority on the device and validate certificate in the software against this. THe only reason I am trying to deffer from kernel compilations is because no big vendors do this either. Google, for example distribute Android with Root certificates against which application are verified to legitimate. Otherwise they would have to compile millions of kernelels everyday which would be madnness.

Comment: That still leaves my code open to easy decryption / analysis. I need not to sign but to encrypt some things. I wouldn't even mind if someone would use the Radpberry for any purposes he likes, as long as it doesn't go the oter way 'round: Running *this* instance of the software on another/man other Raspberries. Think of tokenless "poor man's software security token".

Comment: This is really difficult. One way I have seen devices lock codes away is using a SIM card. Yea, it needs extra interface but then you lock each sim card to the serial number of the Pi (like a pin number) So with out serial number (or any other ocmbination of prgramitc and obscured key) you cant get the data on the card. I see these in Sattelite boxes so that Linux, modified by the vendor has to read the card, before it will load the "kernel/image" image. Maybe have a look into that and see if you can repalce the sim card with something in the kernel?

Comment: I was sort of hoping for a piece of kernel code / patch that would check the cpu's serial number "on boot", ie. once it is called, then only proceeds booting if that serial number is identical to a given ID or list/range of IDs.

Comment: I would really go over to Ubuntu Stack and ask that question, specifically. How to read serial numbers on kernel boot before carrying on. There are guys there that will know how to deal with that. You can then try it out and expand from there. Good Luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the CPU serial, but you might have luck modifying the [Ethernet module](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.10.y/drivers/net/usb/smsc95xx.c) to check the current MAC address against a programmed one. Include that driver in the kernel, and then you should be able to trigger a kernel panic that locks up the device if it doesn't match.

The `smsc95xx_init_mac_address` function looks promising. Check [line 827](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.10.y/drivers/net/usb/smsc95xx.c#L827). Modified version here:

```
    if (smsc95xx_read_eeprom(dev, EEPROM_MAC_OFFSET, ETH_ALEN,
            dev->net->dev_addr) == 0) {
        if (is_valid_ether_addr(dev->net->dev_addr)) {
            // check against a registered MAC address
            if (dev->net->dev_addr[0] != 0xB8 || dev->net->dev_addr[1] != 0x27 || dev->net->dev_addr[2] != 0xEB || dev->net->dev_addr[3] != 0xFF || dev->net->dev_addr[4] != 0xFF || dev->net->dev_addr[5] != 0xFF) {
                // kernel panic if it doesn't match!
                panic("Invalid device!!!!\n");
            }
            /* eeprom values are valid so use them */
            netif_dbg(dev, ifup, dev->net, "MAC address read from EEPROM\n");
            return;
        }
    }
```

I've added a check against the MAC address B8:27:EB:FF:FF:FF, which if any one of the 6 portions don't match, will cause the kernel to panic. (dev_addr is a pointer to a u8 array of 6 elements, which is to say six 8-bit integers... the MAC address.)

Comment: Great idea - plus, it should work on non-Raspian Systems. Thanks for the idea, I'll try this asap.